# Basic unit test to check if I have read access to a field - Apex

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm currently working on a generic way of implementing FLS on all SOQL calls in my code base.

I want to start by creating a few basic unit tests in Apex to check whether or not I have read access to certain fields.

Could someone point me in the direction of some basic unit tests that could check whether or not I have access to a field?

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test field level read access with:

```
Schema.SObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.fields.MyCustomField__c.isAccessible();
```

Within a test method you can use `System.runAs(User)` to wrap the call and check the accessibility based on the users profile.

See also:

- [Testing CRUD and FLS Enforcement](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Testing_CRUD_and_FLS_Enforcement)
- [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS)

Comment: Taken from the [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm), "The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing."